# Can inherited method access subclass fields in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I'm having trouble understanding inheritance.  In the code below, why doesn't the inherited method access the field in the subclass?  Is there any way to access the subclass field without overriding the inherited method?

```
class Fish {
    private String fishType = "Fish";
    public String getFishType() {
        return fishType;
    }
}

class Marlin extends Fish {
    private String fishType = "Marlin";
}

public class InheritanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fish fish1 = new Fish();
        Fish marlin1 = new Marlin();
        System.out.println(fish1.getFishType());
        System.out.println(marlin1.getFishType());
    }
}
```

This code prints

```
Fish
Fish
```

but I was expecting

```
Fish
Marlin
```

---

Everyone seems to be answering based on the strings being private, yet even if I change the fields to public I still have the problem.  The question isn't about inheriting private fields.

Please see updated code below.

```
class Fish {
    public String fishType = "Fish";
    public String getFishType() {
        return fishType;
    }
}

class Marlin extends Fish {
    public String fishType = "Marlin";
}

public class InheritanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fish fish1 = new Fish();
        Marlin marlin1 = new Marlin();
        System.out.println(fish1.getFishType());
        System.out.println(marlin1.getFishType());
    }
}
```

The output and my expectations are the same as above.

Comment: Why is `fishType` not `final static`? Or just an inline String inside of the getter (that would be less ambiguous here). Can it change?

Comment: You changed it from private to package-private (which is quite similar). Try `protected` or `public` and you will get a different result (namely a compile-error about duplicate fields).

Comment: @Thilo  I tried both protected and public and got the same exact results.  Fish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a fair answer by @Makoto I feel the OP question's intend is not properly answered.

The question is about why the re-declared `fishType` in the Marlin class is not honored by the inherited `getFishType()` method when called on an Marlin instance.

This is even more curious when you think of how differently method lookup works (as opposed to field lookup): If you added e.g. a method `Fish::getT()`:`protected String getT() {return "Fish";}` and overrode it in `Marlin::getT()` with `protected String getT() {return "Marlin";}` and called this new method in `Fish::getFishType()` instead of accessing the  field, the call to `marlin1.getFishType()` would actually produce "Marlin". - Here, the subclass method is used in the inherited method, not the parent method of the same name. This is because method lookup always starts at the current instance.

I think the answer is indicated by the quote from the Java docs given by @Makoto: The re-declared field "hides" all other accessible declarations of the same name in the inheritance hierarchy (whereas a re-declared method "overrides" previous declarations of the same name and signature). I take this to mean that the `Marlin.fishType` has to be considered like *a completely different symbol* from `Fish.fishType` (with accidentally the same name). And `Fish.getFishType()` just sees its own version of it.

Answer (score 5):

First, fields (and methods) that are `private` are **not** inherited. Your `Marlin` class doesn't even know of its parent field.

Second, Java will pick the most appropriate method to call based on the instance you're using at runtime.  Since `Marlin` doesn't have the method `getFishType` defined, it will use its parents' method.

There are several approaches you can take to this; one of which is overriding the `getFishType` method inside of `Marlin`:

```
@Override
public String getFishType() {
    return fishType;
}
```

With the new code, you're actually [hiding the variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) by redeclaring it inside of `Marlin`.

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class.

That's easily solvable by not redeclaring the variable; rather, assign the value you want at construction time.

```
public Marlin() {
    fishType = "Marlin";
}
```

Alternatively, in a bid to keep the code cleaner, you can restructure your classes in a way that you make use of the parent's method as opposed to overriding it in the child.  This does require a couple of constructors in the parent class.

```
class Fish {
    private final String fishType;

    // Default constructor; used in nominal cases
    public Fish() {
        this("Fish");
    }

    // Constructor used to populate the fishType field
    public Fish(final String fishType) {
        this.fishType = fishType;
    }

    public String getFishType() {
        return fishType;
    }
}

class Marlin extends Fish {
    public Marlin() {
        super("Marlin"); // invoke super's constructor
    }
}
```

Once again, since there's no suitable method `getFishType` in `Marlin`, it will look to the `Fish` class and use its method instead.  This time, however, the value we actually want to come through is the one we expect.

Comment: @Makoto the 2nd part of your answer seems to be the clearest.  Not sure why it is -1.  But I guess I still don't understand why `Marlin` doesn't have the `getFishType` method.  I thought it was inherited from the `Fish` class.

Comment: It is inherited; it's just not making use of the same field in the child as the parent.  I can show you an example that would work without the need to override the method, but it'd require changing around a few things about the structure of the class.

Comment: That alternative solution looks best.

Comment: @Makoto Thank you for the alternate solution.  Any chance you could expand on "It is inherited; it's just not making use of the same field in the child as the parent."?  Or point me in the right direction?  I can't seem to find anything that explains why the inherited method is only seeing the superclass's fields and not the class I am calling it from.  Thanks.

Comment: I've went a head and revised the answer a bit to include some information that takes your newer code into account.  Note that again the private field isn't acknowledged inside of the child class; this is due to the way the `private` visibility modifier works.  This I must regrettably leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Makoto, thank you for all the help.  I added another edit to my question, showing my code with the constructors.  I would upvote you if I could but I only have a reputation of 6 ;)  I marked it as answered.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to give you a hand, but it's not really necessary to edit your question with that.  The answers are meant to capture the ultimate result.

Answer (score 1):

you have to override  `getFishType()` in Marlin class. private property is only visible within a class.

Comment: I changed the fields to public, but it doesn't help.

Comment: you should override getFishType() method in Marlin class. otherwise you can access using marlin1.fishType, but it is not advisable (it works, but violate encapsulation oop concept).

Answer (score 0):

You should override `getFishType()`, not just `fishType`. The method is inherited but the private properties are not.